# How to get card_nonce in square?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, square, odoo-11

How can I get or create "card_nonce" in the square payment acquire without using SqPaymentForm in CreateCustomerCard?
I want to use that in Odoo s2s payment method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to get a card nonce programmatically, you must use the payment form.

Comment: Thanks, Can I use multi-currency in e-commerce sale payments?

Comment: You can only charge in the currency of your square account when you make the request, but you can use currency conversion rates to display other prices to the buyer.